# Blocking movement on collision while centered on point

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, accelerometer

I'm making a small game in which a character is moved in a 2D world using the iPhone accelerometer. Tilting the phone left or right doesn't move the character's x position, but the rest of the world, each "layer" of the world having different speeds.

My problem is that I would like that my character "stops" (i.e. the rest of the world stops moving) when it encounters an obstacle.

This is what I've come up with so far.

```
let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()

// the (fixed) x position of the character 
let startingPositionX: CGFloat = 150

// in the "update()" function of the SKScene
if let accelerometerData = motionManager.accelerometerData { 
    // the x part of the acceleration (the iphone is sideways)
    let acc = CGFloat(accelerometerData.acceleration.y)
    // the character 
    let hero = self.childNodeWithName("hero") as! Hero

    // when the hero "touches" a block, it slightly pushes it back
    let deltaX = startingPositionX - hero.position.x

    if abs(acc) > 0.05 { 
        let accNorm = max(acc, 0) * CGFloat(deltaX <= 0) + 
                      min(acc, 0) * CGFloat(deltaX >= 0)
        // this method moves all the sprites of the scene by their defined quantity
        // (foreground being faster than background)
        self.spriteManager.update(accNorm)
    }
    // put the character back in its original position
    hero.position.x = startingPositionX
}
```

Now this feels *very* hackish, and it "almost" works, but for some reason, the character will sometime not be able to go back to its original position, despite the line `hero.position.x = startingPositionX` being called. This makes the deltaX always nonzero and blocks the movement in one direction.

I don't see how I could implement this using collisions, and the only other solution I see would be to change the logic and use some kind of cameras, which would make the parallax effect of the different layers of nodes much harder to implement. Could there be a better way?